# How to substract multiple .x from .y with same prefixes

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

**I have this tibble:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 8
    a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2
2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0
```

```
df <- structure(list(a.x = c(13L, 17L), b.x = c(13L, 11L), c.x = c(12L, 
0L), d.x = c(11L, 0L), a.y = c(7L, 16L), b.y = 1:2, c.y = c(4L, 
0L), d.y = c(2L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**I want to calculate:** `a.x - a.y`, `b.x - b.y`, `c.x - c.y`, and so on ....

**My desired output:**

```
    a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y     a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2     6    12     8     9
2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0     1     9     0     0
```

I can achieve this by:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(a = a.x-a.y,
           b = b.x-b.y,
           c = c.x-c.y,
           d = d.x-d.y)
```

**I want to learn:**

1. How to extract the prefixes to new column names.
2. Automate the calculation `.x - .y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method with `cur_column` - loop over the columns that `ends_with` `.x`, replace the substring in the column name (`cur_column()`) by changing the 'x' to 'y', `get` the value, subtract and change the column names in `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(ends_with('.x'),
     ~ . - get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'x', 'y')), 
         .names = "{str_remove(.col, fixed('.x'))}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 12
    a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y     a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2     6    12     8     9
2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0     1     9     0     0
```

---

or with reshaping by `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value"), 
          names_pattern = "(.)\\..*") %>% 
     group_by(rn) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ -diff(.))) %>%
     select(-rn) %>%
     bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 2 x 12
 a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y     a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2     6    12     8     9
2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0     1     9     0     0
```

Comment: @TarJae It does work.  I remember that you may have tested the `tidymodels` and those package functions may have masked it.  I tried on a fresh R session with only these packages and the `fixed` is working correctly

Answer (score 4):

A **base R** approach for you:

```
cbind(df, mapply(\(x, y) x - y, df[endsWith(names(df), ".x")],
                 df[endsWith(names(df), ".y")]) |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        setNames(letters[seq_len(ncol(df)/2)]))

  a.x b.x c.x d.x a.y b.y c.y d.y a  b c d
1  13  13  12  11   7   1   4   2 6 12 8 9
2  17  11   0   0  16   2   0   0 1  9 0 0
```

A similar `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  bind_cols(
    map2_df(".x", ".y", ~ df[grepl(.x, names(df))] - df[grepl(.y, names(df))]) %>%
      rename_with(~ gsub(".x", "", .), everything())
  )
```

A very simple and compact approach suggested by dear [@Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712/henrik)

```
cbind(df, setNames(df[endsWith(names(df), ".x")] - df[endsWith(names(df), ".y")], 
                   sub("\\..*","", names(df[endsWith(names(df), ".x")]))))
```

Comment: Thank you Anoushiravan. Would `map` help in this situation? :-)

Comment: Yes this way maybe with `map2`. Not the best choice though I suppose. Arun's first solution would've been my first choice without hesitation. I learned that from him in fact lol.

Comment: simple and elegant

Answer (score 3):

I have a package on github {dplyover} for this kind of operations. We could use `dplyover::across2` to make the calculation. If we specify `"{pre}"` in the `.names` argument, we can extract the common prefix of each pair of variables.

The main advantage to regular {dplyr} solutions is that we do not necessarily need columns with similar names. The downside is that `across2` is less performant than `dplyr::across`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover


df %>%
  mutate(across2(ends_with(".x"),
                 ends_with(".y"),
                 ~ .x - .y,
                 .names = "{pre}"))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 12
#>     a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y     a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2     6    12     8     9
#> 2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0     1     9     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Very intersting. Thank you for sharing this info. I will download and try your package!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('x'),  .names = "{str_remove(.col, '.x')}")
         - across(ends_with('y')))
# A tibble: 2 x 12
    a.x   b.x   c.x   d.x   a.y   b.y   c.y   d.y     a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    13    13    12    11     7     1     4     2     6    12     8     9
2    17    11     0     0    16     2     0     0     1     9     0     0
```

In base R, you could use the `split.default`:

```
a <- do.call('-', split.default(df, sub('.', '', names(df)))) 
cbind(df, setNames(a, sub('..$', '', names(a))))
  a.x b.x c.x d.x a.y b.y c.y d.y a  b c d
1  13  13  12  11   7   1   4   2 6 12 8 9
2  17  11   0   0  16   2   0   0 1  9 0 0
```

Comment: This is awesome too. across - across. Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic lesson Onyambu.  Upvoted already :)

Comment: Onyambu, I am waiting for your approach at this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/68564367/2884859 please have a look in your time