# How can I use a vectorised function in R in alternate sequence?

Tags: r, sequence, modulo

Suppose I have a vector `x` with `n` elements.  I want to use any vectorised function, say `cumprod`, on every alternate number of `x`, i.e. every 1, 3, 5 and so on and another on 2, 4, 6 and so on.  I am adding a reprex and code tried.  The code works, but it seems I am unnecessarily taking a long route and code can be shortened.  Can it be?

```r
x <- 5:14

cumprod((x * (seq_along(x) %% 2)) + (seq_along(x)-1) %% 2) * seq_along(x) %% 2 +
  cumprod((x * ((seq_along(x)-1) %% 2)) + seq_along(x) %% 2) * (seq_along(x)-1) %% 2
#>  [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

Here `cumprod` is just an example function.  I may have to use other functions in alternate sequence as well.

Comment: It would be cool if base R had a function equivalent to take-nth in Clojure.

Comment: @BillO'Brien I'm not familiar with Clojure, but how about `y <-  x[seq(1,n,by=2)]` ?  This is basically thelatemail's answer

Comment: wasn't on yesterday. All the answers below are amazing.  Another way is to do `Reduce(function(x, y) c(x, y*tail(x, 2)[1]), x, init = 1)[-1]` Which means you can always change the 2 to any number. ie 3, 4, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could do this in a concise way with `rowCumprods` after creating a `matrix` (assuming the `vector` is of even length)

```
library(matrixStats)
c(rowCumprods(matrix(x, nrow = 2)))
```

-output

```
[1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

---

if it can be odd length, then just append an `NA` at the end

```
 c(rowCumprods(matrix(c(x,  list(NULL, NA)[[1 +
         (length(x) %%2 != 0)]]), nrow = 2)))
```

-output

```
 [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

---

Or we can do this in a generalized way with `ave` (works both with even/odd lengths)

```
ave(x, seq_along(x) %% 2, FUN = cumprod)
 [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

Comment: dear Arun, last one is fantastic.  I think we can use any function in there.  Accepting it.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Select odd (`c(TRUE, FALSE)`) or even (`c(FALSE, TRUE)`) indices. Weave the two resulting vectors (`c(rbind`)

```
c(rbind(cumprod(x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), cumprod(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))
# [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

---

To handle also odd vector length, you need to truncate the result to length of the vector.

```
x = 1:5

c(rbind(cumprod(x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), cumprod(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))[1:length(x)]
# [1]  1  2  3  8 15
```

There will be a warning when the shorter result vector, corresponding to the even indices (which has one element less), is recycled in the `rbind` step.

Comment: Actually I want something like this only.  But will it work when x has odd number of elements?

Answer (score 6):

One option for both even and odd number of elements could be:

```
c(t(apply(matrix(x, 2, sum(seq_along(x) %% 2)), 1, cumprod)))[1:length(x)]
```

With `x <- 1:5`:

```
[1]  1  2  3  8 15
```

With `x <- 1:6`:

```
[1]  1  2  3  8 15 48
```

Or a less effective option, however, without any warnings:

```
y <- Reduce(`c`, sapply(split(setNames(x, seq_along(x)), !seq_along(x) %% 2), cumprod))
y[order(as.numeric(names(y)))]
```

Comment: The reduce one, you could just have `Reduce(function(x, y) c(x, y*tail(x, 2)[1]), x, init = 1)[-1]`

Comment: @Onyambu this is a beautiful option! I think you should post it as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Another option - take a sequence and then fill the results back in:

```
x <- 5:14

s <- seq(1, length(x), 2)
o <- x
o[s]  <- cumprod(x[s])
o[-s] <- cumprod(x[-s])
o 
# [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

Or if you want to code-golf it:

```
s <- seq(1, length(x), 2)
replace(replace(x, s, cumprod(x[s])), -s, cumprod(x[-s]))
# [1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

Comment: Better late than never.  Fantastic approach.  I like this one because, I can apply any vectorised function here without taking care the identity here.  Thanks.  Needless to say +1 already

Comment: Thanks once again for your fantastic answer.  Sorry that I cannot two answers, in that case I would have chosen yours.  :)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Solution**

This may sound a bit verbose but it will work with odd and even number of lengths and also @Henrik's custom vector:

```
x <- 5:14
lapply(split(x, !(seq_len(length(x)) %% 2)), cumprod) |>
  setNames(c("a", "b")) |>
  list2env(globalenv())

c(a, b)[order(c(seq_along(a)*2 - 1, seq_along(b)*2))]

[1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045 80640
```

With an odd vector:

```
x <- 5:13
[1]     5     6    35    48   315   480  3465  5760 45045
```

Or with `x = c(1, 0, 3, 4)`

```
[1] 1 0 3 0
```

And in the end with `x = c(2, 4, 2, 4)`:

```
[1]  2  4  4 16
```

Comment: Doesn't the `x%%2` split in odd and even _values_, whereas I think OP wants to split in odd and even _indices_, like `seq_along(x) %% 2`? Try on e.g. `x = c(2, 4, 2, 4)`. Cheers

Comment: So maybe `l = lapply(split(x, seq_along(x)%%2), cumprod)`; `c(l[[2]], l[[1]])[order(c(seq_along(l[[2]]), seq_along(l[[1]])))]`

Comment: Please check my modified, ultimate version :D

Comment: I didn't use `seq_along(x) %% 2` as it would've been similar to Thomas code. So this I think will do.

Comment: Excellent! (I hope you don't mind my comments. I just try to learn from other answers, and when playing around I sometimes stumble on things that have potential for tweeking, often a result of my own struggles with my own attempts). Cheers

Comment: No not at all. In fact I really appreciate you took your time to critic my solution, cause these discussions while we grapple with the issue by tweaking and changing is a great way to learn. I am still the least experienced contributor here and it's a great honor for me to be learning from you guys. Thank you again.

Comment: We only learn in time of struggling and being overwhelmed, when you feel there remains nothing more you could do to get a solution to work is usually one or two steps to success :)